# How to test apache server on Ubuntu Server 10.04 running in VirtualBox?

Tags: 10.04, server, virtualbox, apache2, testing

I installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 via VirtualBox, yes, the I use virtual machine, cuz I am learning ubuntu. I installed apache webserver by this command:

```
sude apt-get install apache2
```

Everything looks okay, no error. Now, how do I test if the apache server is working? Normally in windows OS, after install apache, I go to web browser, point to 127.0.0.1, and the webpage will display "it works". How do I test my ubuntu server web apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test your Apache setup from the host machine, you will need to configure your networking in VirtualBox. There is a great tutorial on that [here](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2010/03/22/virtualbox-networking-setup/). Then you would point the browser in your host machine to whatever IP address is assigned to the guest.

Answer (score 1):

Either install a text mode browser like w3m or lynx on your server and use that to connect to localhost, or connect from the outside world to your VirtualBox

Comment: Hi, your second solution: "connect from the outside world to your VirtualBox", how to achieve that?

Comment: that depends on your network connection... but for quick test you can install miredo on your server and on your client ( it will give both of them ipv6 adress, so you dont have to setup port forwarding ), then run ifconfig | grep "Scope:Global" on your server to see ipv6 adress... and just copy it to your clients webbrowser. In chromium it will look like http://[2001:15c0:****:***::2]

Comment: @ubuntuka The solution described in DLH's answer should get you a nretwork connection between host and guest. Just use guest's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [VirtualBox documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes), you have up to 6 networking modes to choose from:

1. Not attached - No connection in Guest OS
2. Network Address Translation (NAT) - Default selection mode, allowing guest connection to access internet
3. Bridged networking - Allow your Guest OS to connect to the network just like another device in the network. (What I normally use)
4. Internal networking - Not clear.
5. Host-only networking - Allow connection between host and guests only.
6. Generic networking - Not clear.

So if you want to test your Ubuntu Server 10.04 in your VirtualBox, you can choose either Bridged Networking or Host-only Networking.

If you are using the Bridged Networking which I have tested, you will have to find out your Guest OS IP address. In desktop mode, it is as simple as clicking (or right-click) the Network Manager -> Connection Information.

[image: Connection Information]